# Word for long chain of causes

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What may be the conceptual, phenomenal word for

> a long chain of complex causes and reasons, that doesn't believe in coincidences, accidentalities, karma etc.?

Comment: I think your question isn't clear.  Please edit the question and provide more context, examples, or discussion.

Comment: **di•a•lec•tic** (ˌdaɪ əˈlɛk tɪk) *adj.* Also, **dialectical**.  **7**. the juxtaposition or interaction of conflicting ideas, forces, etc. [sourced to Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010] See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dialectical -- Is that something you have in mind?

Comment: .......history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [concatenation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concatenation?s=t) may be what you're looking for.

> Concatenation (n): a series of interconnected or interdependent things or events.